# HTTP response generator webservice

Tags: api, http, rest, testing, response

There are many ways to test HTTP requests, like Postman or Advanced REST Client for Chrome. The opposite, to test responses for request is not readily available.

**Is there a webservice that allows one to specify a HTTP response (code, headers, body) and saves it in a unique URL?** One can then test his requests again a known fake API.

Something like

```
GET http://domain.com/21312831203
```

and I get the response that I specified before?

Something just for codes is available at http://httpstat.us/,  however, it is not possible to set headers and a body there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of such a service that exists today, but you could easily make a small [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) app that hard-codes test responses to HTTP requests:

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'

# http_responses.rb
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)

get '/21312831203' do
  status 403
  headers 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'
  body "Pre-recorded body"
end
```

`bundle install && ruby http_responses.rb` should run the above program. See the [Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) for more details on what APIs you could call in order to mock requests.

Comment: Is there anything that you recommend using Python? A term to google would also be helpful :)